# rows.indexOf(row) on lighning:datatable does not work anymore on Spring 20 (getting selected row)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, spring-20

We are experiencing an issue with a Lightning Component since the Spring 20 release.
This LC component contains a lightning:datatable on which we can perform actions on a specific row.
For that, on the controller side we use (as specified in official documentation) event.getParam('row'); and then rows.indexOf(row); to retrieve the selected row.
To make sure the issue is not related to my actual code, I recreated a very basic Lighning app with a LC that contains a ligthning:datatable.

- When I launch an action from first row, I get "rowIndex is -1" instead of "rowIndex is 0".
- When I launch an action from second row, I get "rowIndex is -1" instead of "rowIndex is 1".

To make sure the issue is related to Spring 20, I deployed this Lightning app to our Production org which is still in Winter 20 and I get successful results :

- When I launch an action from first row, I get "rowIndex is 0" as expected
- When I launch an action from second row, I get "rowIndex is 1" as expected

So I really believe this is a bug related to Spring 20 as we did not change our code at all and it was working perfectly in Winter 20 release.

I am wondering if anybody is expecting the same issue as us, and most importantly if anybody has a workaround for this.

Thanks

Temp.app

```
    <aura:application extends="force:slds">
     <c:Temp_Test />
   </aura:application>
```

Temp_Test.cmp

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

<div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
    <lightning:layout verticalAlign="start" multipleRows="true" class="slds-box slds-size_4-of-4">


        <lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }"
            columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
            keyField="id"
            onrowaction="{! c.getSelectedRow }"/>


    </lightning:layout>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Temp_TestController

```
({
init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var actions = [
        { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' }
    ];
    cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
        { label: 'Opportunity', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'},
        { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone'},
        { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } }
    ]);

        cmp.set('v.mydata', [{
                opportunityName: 'Cloudhub',
                phone: '2352235235'
            },
            {
                opportunityName: 'Quip',
                phone: '2352235235'
        }]);
},
getSelectedRow: function (cmp, event) {
    var row = event.getParam('row');
    var rows = cmp.get('v.mydata');
    var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row);
    alert("Row index is : " + rowIndex);
}
 })
```

Screenshot : 
[image]

**EDIT :** 
I found a workaround : Instead of using rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row); , I am directly accessing properties of my row with row.someProperty.
But still, that does not explain why indexOf() always return -1.

Comment: can you `console.log(event.getParams())` to see what is currently being emitted in total, instead of just looking at one specific parameter

Comment: @BryanAnderson I edited my question. Actually event.getParam('row') works fine. It actually has to do with rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row); It always returns -1. I have checked the values of row and rows in the console and they happen to contain the same row values. It was working perfectly in the Winter 20 release.

Comment: I don't think it is wise to perform an `indexOf` method call on an array using an object (I.e. `row`). I am assuming you want to get the data of a particular row correct?

Comment: Yes that's what I want.  I found a workaround : Instead of using rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row); , I am directly accessing properties of my row with row.someProperty. But still, that does not explain why indexOf() always return -1. And that is what Salesforce recommends to do on official doc : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation